# Ag-grid full width rows does not appear to work with React Components

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here or if the documentation is wrong or misleading.  I am trying to use the FullWidthRowCell feature for detail panels for each row.  However, it appears not to completely work as documented.  As I recently made the jump from v4 to v6 of ag-grid, I thought I would ask here if I was in error before making a bug report of this.

Description:

I changed an existing data grid so that I would potentially have a details panel that expands out to show additional info in another format.  I also wanted to use a react component that I would be reusing elsewhere.  Currently, the panel will open and show only a blank area (where the panel should be) and produce an error message.  I have used the "cellRendererFramework" successfully in my column definitions.

Documentation references:

section: **Full Width Rows & Master Detail Grids**

> Provide a fullWidthCellRenderer, to tell the grid what cellRenderer to
>   use when doing fullWidth rendering.
>
> The cellRenderer can be any ag-Grid cellRenderer. Refer to Cell
>   Rendering on how to build cellRenderers. The cellRenderer for
>   fullWidth has one difference to normal cellRenderers, that is the
>   parameters passed are missing the value and column information as the
>   cellRenderer, by definition, is not tied to a particular column.
>   Instead you should work off the data parameter, which represents the
>   value for the entire row.

section:  **React Cell Rendering**, *Specifying a React cellRenderer*

> This same mechanism can be to use a React Component in the following
>   locations:
>
> ```
> colDef.cellRendererFramework
> colDef.floatingCellRendererFramework
> gridOptions.fullWidthCellRendererFramework
> gridOptions.groupRowRendererFramework
> gridOptions.groupRowInnerRendererFramework
> ```

**gridOptions.fullWidthCellRendererFramework** is a specified option!

Example setup:

Below is some of the import parts of my settings (yes its omitting col definitions and other stuff that are in my actual version).

grid options(snippet):

```
gridOptions = {
  doesDataFlower: (data) => { return true; }
  isFullWidthCell: function(rowNode) {
      var rowIsNestedRow = rowNode.flower;
      return rowIsNestedRow;
  },
  getRowHeight: function(params) {
    var rowIsNestedRow = params.node.flower;
    return rowIsNestedRow ? 100 : 25;
  },
  fullWidthCellRendererFramework: AppointmentDetail
}
```

A simple stub test component that I tried

```
class AppointmentDetail extends React.Component<any, any>
{
    render() {
        return <div>AppointmentDetail</div>
    }
}
```

However, if I use non-react method

```
fullWidthCellRenderer: (params) => { return "<div>Test</div>"; }
```

or the old method for react components (which I thought was not intended by the author to be used anymore)

```
fullWidthCellRenderer: reactCellRendererFactory(AppointmentDetail)
```

then the full row renders properly.

Warnings:

```
ag-Grid: you need to provide a fullWidthCellRenderer if using isFullWidthCell()
```

The component does kindly provide me an error that tells me what is wrong.  It is just the documentation seems to indicate that this should be valid.

Version:
Just in case this is needed... here is my version taken from my webpack dependencies.

```
"ag-grid": "^6.0.1",
"ag-grid-react": "^6.0.1",
"react": "^15.3.2",
```

Edit(s):

I edited gridProps to gridOptions to better illustrate that these are the grid options that I am giving ag-grid.  It appears this was not clear, based on the response that told me to do exactly what I stated I did and did not work.

Added react version.

Comment: apparently a fix has been found for the [github issue](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1182) made.  Unfortunately I have not had a chance to verify the fix.

Answer (score 2):

In 6.x the mechanism to supply components (either Angular 2 or React ones) was simplified a bit, and unified.

To supply a component in 6.x use the following syntax:

```
gridOptions.fullWidthCellRendererFramework = AppointmentDetail
```

Its a similar idea for the rest of the renderers (some user colDef.XxxRendererFramework, others use gridOptions.xxxxRendererFramework).

See https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#reactCellRendering for more information around this

Comment: Ok and this does not work... this was what I wrote.  My "gridprops" is essentially equal to your examples "gridOptions", it is only named like this because I have a wrapper in React around your component.  I guess I didn't make that obvious enough.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the ag-Grid React component?

i am thinking you are using ag-Grid in a React application, but not actually using the React component.

are you using AgGridReact like this:

```
<AgGridReact

  // listen for events with React callbacks
  onRowSelected={this.onRowSelected.bind(this)}
  onCellClicked={this.onCellClicked.bind(this)}

  // binding to properties within React State or Props
  showToolPanel={this.state.showToolPanel}
  quickFilterText={this.state.quickFilterText}
  icons={this.state.icons}

  // column definitions and row data are immutable, the grid
  // will update when these lists change
  columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
  rowData={this.state.rowData}

  // or provide props the old way with no binding
  rowSelection="multiple"
  enableSorting="true"
  enableFilter="true"
  rowHeight="22"
/>
```

Comment: import {AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';

Comment: since that is my import, I would assume I am using the correct component.

<div style={{height: '100%'}} className="ag-blue">
   <AgGridReact {...gridProps}/>
</div>