# Ag Grid React : Full Width Row with "Group"

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

This is an extension to [Ag-grid full width rows does not appear to work with React Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708491/ag-grid-full-width-rows-does-not-appear-to-work-with-react-components)

I'm able to get the Full With Rows displayed OK.
But I'm having trouble in getting the  expand collapse functionality in the full Width Row.
I tried

```
fullWidthCellRendererFramework = {(params)=>{return <span>test</span>}}
```

along with

> cellRenderer: 'group'

in one of the columns like mentioned in
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-full-width-rows/?framework=javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, `groupUseEntireRow: true` in your gridOptions.

**explaination:** *groupUseEntireRow*   - If grouping, set to true or false (default is false). If true, a group row will span all columns across the entire width of the table. If false, the cells will be rendered as normal and you will have the opportunity to include a grouping column (normally the first on the left) to show the group.